# Power Automate Multiple Columns of type Multi Select To Populate Word Template

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, powerapps

I have a flow where I need to populate a word template problem I have multiple columns(More than 5) which are of type Multi Select so now to avoid having each column creating FOR EACH how can I achieve this without not having to create multiple Selects and Join for each column [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkXIQ.png)